# where did Microsoft's own syslog server for Windows go?

Tags: windows, syslog

I think I remember Microsoft shipping a syslog server feature as part of one of its server products, either Proxy Server or System Management server or something. Where did that go?

Answer (score 3):

The Operations Manager line can do that.  The current product is called System Center Operations Manager (SCOM) and succeeded Microsoft Operations Manager a few years ago.

[KB 942863: How to collect and monitor UNIX Syslogs in System Center Operations Manager 2007 or in System Center Essentials 2007](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942863)